# Google Play Services number format

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am getting the Google Play Services version number this way:

```
public long GetGooglePlayServicesVersion(Context oContext){

    try {
        long v = PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(oContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE, 0));
        return v;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

But it returns a number like **15090019** corresponding to real version number **"15.0.90"**.

How can I format that number to look like the real version number? Is there a way to get the "string" look of the version number?